# Easier way to Call a SOAP Service with Many Parameters?

Tags: wcf, soap

My web services are rusty so I hope I'm just missing something kind of obvious.

I have a WCF service that, in part, relays calls it receives to a third party SOAP service.  The service receives an object that matches the body of the SOAP message that needs to be sent.

I've added a service reference based on the SOAP service's WSDL to the project and created and instance of the service proxy class.  The service method I want to call has 30+ parameters.

I could call it with `MyService.TheMethod(obj.value1, obj.value2, obj.value3...)`, but it would be nice to just pass the original object on or XML serialize it and pass the XML as a body.

Is there something that would allow an easier approach or do I need to individually pass obj's properties onto the SOAP method?

**UPDATE**

Clarifying the underlying issue.

My .NET service accepts something "Group"

```
public class Person { string Name; int Age;}
public class Group { string Name; Person[] Individuals; }
```

I then need to call the third party web service (TPWS).  The proxy class generated from the WSDL winds up like:

```
public class WSPerson { string Name; uint Age;}
public class WSGroup { string Name; WSPerson[] Individuals; }
```

I'd been doing earlier prototyping and working with the TPWS through SoapUI and using tags matching my original (.NET) classes' naming:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.myabc123.com" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:sys="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ws:ServiceCredentials>
         <ws:SubscriberId>ABC</ws:SubscriberId>
         <ws:SubscriberUser>Joe</ws:SubscriberUser>
         <ws:SubscriberPassword>12345</ws:SubscriberPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:SubscriberIdentityStore></ws:SubscriberIdentityStore>
      </ws:ServiceCredentials>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <Group>
      <Name>Cool People</Name>
      <Individuals>
        <Person>
          <Name>Tom</Name>
          <Age>25</Age>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <Name>Jane</Name>
          <Age>27</Age>
        </Person>
      </Individuals>
    </Group>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do what you want. If the service you're calling has 30 parameters, you'll just have to call it with 30 parameters.

Comment: Or create a "data container" class that holds those 30 parameters - and then pass that one container class to the method (if that method is written that way...)

Comment: Which I can do.  The third party tool is a mapping tool that generates a web service for you.  By changing what it expects, that can ripple outwards.  But, I've since realized that the rabbit hole is deeper as the 30+ objects include a number of complex objects with different naming and different types (similar and castable, but different nonetheless).

Comment: So, sometimes object "X" is of type "Y" and sometimes it's type "Z"? Then perhaps you can remap into two operations, one where "X" is always a "Y" and the other where "X" is always a "Z"?

Comment: I receive X and pass it on to the third party service.  The service's proxy class is type Y.  Both X and Y were created by .NET (X) and 3rd Party (Y) derived from the same XSD.  I'll add a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help others.  I'm pursuing the idea of [calling the web service through HTTP POST](http://forums.asp.net/t/928000.aspx).

The reason is that this general problem will be repeated in similar ways over and over.  I control the incoming data contract and the format of the XML that the 3rd party mapping tool ultimately expects.  But it generates its own contract for the service.  If it can recognize the raw XML that I can produce through XmlSerializer I won't have to map my class just to get the 3rd party tool to in turn perform its own mapping functions.